# Parsing a string containing logic to create Django Q objects

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I'm adding reporting functionality to a django web application which includes being able to chain filters while defining the logic eg `(1 OR 2 OR 4) AND 4`

Currently the data structure being utilised is:

```
`{'logic': u'(1 OR 2 OR 4) AND 4',
 'query': [{u'field': u'first_name',
            u'id': 1,
            u'opertor': u'icontains',
            u'value': u'A'},
           {u'field': u'first_name',
            u'id': 2,
            u'opertor': u'icontains',
            u'value': u'b'},
           {u'field': u'show_tag',
            u'id': 3,
            u'opertor': u'includes',
            u'value': u'1955'},
           {u'field': u'organisation__organisation_name',
            u'id': 4,
            u'opertor': u'icontains',
            u'value': u'a'}]}`
```

To convert the logic from a string to a nested list I'm using the following:

```
from pyparsing import nestedExpr

def parse_brackets(val):
    val = '(' + val + ')'
    parsed = nestedExpr('(',')').parseString(val).asList()
    return parsed
```

For the example above this returns `[[['1', 'OR', '2', 'OR', '4'], 'AND', '4']]`

What I'm finding challenging is parsing this data structure so that it can be translated into chained `Q()` objects. I have tried using BFS to search through the structure but am unable to associate the AND/OR correctly to the surrounding criteria

Any advice greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function that looks for an `OR` or an `AND` operator in a given list of tokens and slice the list at the index where it is found, and recursively processes the the two sliced lists on either sides of the operator and apply the corresponding methods (`Q.__or__` and `Q.__and__`) to the returning `Q` objects. If no operator is found, return a new `Q` object with the referenced query data:

```
def q(query, tokens):
    if isinstance(tokens, list):
        for operator in ('OR', 'AND'): # OR first since it has a lower precedence than AND
            try:
                index = tokens.index(operator)
                break
            except ValueError:
                pass
        else:
            return q(query, tokens[0])
        return (Q.__or__ if operator == 'OR' else Q.__and__)(
            q(query, tokens[:index]), q(query, tokens[index + 1:]))
    else:
        d = query[int(tokens)]
        return Q(**{'__'.join((d['field'], d['operator'])): d['value']})
```

so that given:

```
tokens = [[['1', 'OR', '2', 'OR', '4'], 'AND', '4']]
query = {'logic': u'(1 OR 2 OR 4) AND 4',
         'query': [{u'field': u'first_name',
                    u'id': 1,
                    u'opertor': u'icontains',
                    u'value': u'A'},
                   {u'field': u'first_name',
                    u'id': 2,
                    u'opertor': u'icontains',
                    u'value': u'b'},
                   {u'field': u'show_tag',
                    u'id': 3,
                    u'opertor': u'includes',
                    u'value': u'1955'},
                   {u'field': u'organisation__organisation_name',
                    u'id': 4,
                    u'opertor': u'icontains',
                    u'value': u'a'}]}
query = {q['id']: q for q in query['query']} # transform the above to a dict indexed by id
```

`q(query, tokens)` should return the `Q` object you need.

Disclaimer: I did not test this code.